# Dataweave is not creating only one record instead of 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I want to create 4 records per object from the payload shown below.
Each key has it own mapping which is an integer (ASC__c,CDF23__c,Option_Set__c,Statement_Message_ID__c) which is going to be the ":USRDSB:-FIELD-IND".

**Input JSON **

```
[
  {
        "Statement_Message_ID__c": "15673",
        "Option_Set__c": "801",
        "TSYS_ID__c": "12346849",
        "ASC__c": "V01",
        "CDF23__c": "1"
    },
    {
        "Statement_Message_ID__c": "15839",
        "Option_Set__c": "813",
        "TSYS_ID__c": "12347015",
        "ASC__c": "V01",
        "CDF23__c": "1"
    }
]
```

I have the below dw script. I am iterating over each object in the payload where the size is 2 and I have created an Array **fieldDataArray** which has a size of 4.
So, for each object it has to create 4 records in the flat file. But the script is creating only one per **TSYS_ID__c**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/flatfile schemaPath = "schemas/VP.ffd", structureIdent="MultiSegment"
var fieldDataArray= 0 to 3
fun filterKey(keyName, keyArray) = sizeOf(keyArray filter ((item, index) -> item ~= keyName ))==1
---
{
    vps: {
        vps: [{
            ":USRDSB:-SOURCE": {
                ":USRDSB:-SOURCE": "SOURCE",
                ":USRDSB:-SOURCE-ID ": "MULESOFT"
            },
            ":USRDSB:-HEADER": {
                ":USRDSB:-HEADER": "HEADER",
                ":USRDSB:-TRANSMISSION-ID": "VTY"
            },
            ":USRDSB:-DETAIL-RECORD": payload map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
                
                ( fieldDataArray map  {
                    ":USRDSB:-FIELD-IND": flatten(payload01 pluck $$) match {
                        case k if(filterKey("Option_Set__c",flatten(payload01 pluck $$)) and $$ == 0) -> "019303" as Number 
                        case k if(filterKey("Statement_Message_ID__c",flatten(payload01 pluck $$)) and $$ == 1) -> "014205" as Number
                        case k if(filterKey("CDF23__c",flatten(payload01 pluck $$)) and $$ == 2) -> "008902"  as Number
                        case k if(filterKey("ASC__c",flatten(payload01 pluck $$)) and $$ == 3) -> "011206" as Number
                        else -> "1" as Number
 
                   }
                   
 
                }),
                 ":USRDSB:-CARD-NBR": payload01.TSYS_ID__c,
                    ":USRDSB:-CUST-IND": "D",
                    ":USRDSB:-FIELD-DATA": payload01.Statement_Message_ID__c
                
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

**FFD:**

```
form: COPYBOOK
structures:
- id: 'MultiSegment'
  name: MultiSegment
  data:
  - groupId: 'vps'
    items:
    - groupId: 'vps'
      count: '>1'
      items:
        - { idRef: ':USRDSB:-SOURCE', count: 1 }
        - { idRef: ':USRDSB:-HEADER', count: 1 }
        - { idRef: ':USRDSB:-DETAIL-RECORD', count: '>1' }
  
segments: 
- id: ':USRDSB:-SOURCE'
  values: 
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-COMMENT-IND', type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: 'FILLER1', usage: U, type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-SOURCE', type: String, length: 6, value: 'SOURCE' }
  - { name: 'FILLER2', usage: U, type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-SOURCE-ID ', type: String, length: 8, value: 'MULESOFT' }
- id: ':USRDSB:-HEADER'
  values: 
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-COMMENT-IND', type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: 'FILLER1', usage: U, type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-HEADER', type: String, length: 6, value: 'HEADER' }
  - { name: 'FILLER2', usage: U, type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-TRANSMISSION-ID', type: String, length: 8, value: 'TBC' }
  - { name: 'FILLER3', usage: U, type: String, length: 1 }
- id: ':USRDSB:-DETAIL-RECORD'
  values: 
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-COMMENT-IND', type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: 'FILLER1', usage: U, type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-FIELD-IND', type: Integer, length: 6, format: { justify: ZEROES, sign: UNSIGNED }}
  - { name: 'FILLER2', usage: U, type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-CARD-NBR', type: String, length: 19 }
  - { name: 'FILLER3', usage: U, type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-CUST-IND', type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: 'FILLER4', usage: U, type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-FIELD-DATA', type: String, length: 80 }
  - { name: 'FILLER5', usage: U, type: String, length: 9 }
```

*Current Output*:

```
  SOURCE MULESOFT
  HEADER VTY      
  011206 12346849            D 15673                                                                                    
  011206 12347015            D 15839
```

**Expected output:**

```
  SOURCE MULESOFT
  HEADER SPLNSCRB
  019303 12346849            352
  008902 12346849            02  
  011206 12346849            D 15673  
  014205 12346849            F0015
  019303 12347015            353
  008902 12347015            03
  011206 12347015            V03
  014205 12347015            F0015
```

```
Layout:
      SOURCE MULESOFT
       HEADER  SPLNSCRB
      Statement_Message_ID__c TSYS_ID__c
      Option_Set__c           TSYS_ID__c
      ASC__c                  TSYS_ID__c
      CDF23__c                TSYS_ID__c
```

I am missing something on the dw. Could someone help me to understand and fix this?

TIA!

Comment: Your expected mapping is not clear. The `FIELD-DATA` from your expected output does not match any field from your input except for the `Statement_Message_ID__c`. Can you explain how the other values, like `352`, `02` etc come in your expected output?

Comment: @HarshankBansal that has a different logic. But, you could try populating some dummy values

Comment: Still, you need to provide some explanation as the dataweave that you have provided does not give any clarity as it is not properly written. With this much info, I can only help with a hint. You are not getting multiple values for each of the items because you are still mapping each object to a single object, what you need to do is to map each object to an array of 4 objects. and then `flatten` it. Or simply you need to use a `flatMap` and then map each object to an array of objects.

Comment: TSYS_ID__c is an user ID. For each TSYS_ID__c in the object I need to create 4 records. First value in the record :USRDSB:-FIELD-IND" holds the integer value of the following fields - Statement_Message_ID__c(019303)","Option_Set__c(014205)","ASC__c(008902)" "CDF23__c(011206)". Right now it is creating only one record per object. See the layout below   `SOURCE MULESOFT
  HEADER SPLNSCRB
  Statement_Message_ID__c TSYS_ID__c
  Option_Set__c TSYS_ID__c
  ASC__c TSYS_ID__c
  CDF23__c TSYS_ID__c`

Comment: @HarshankBansal updated with the layout in the question

Comment: @codebeget you should explain all the details. Do not expect others to complete your question for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is incomplete but if you want to generate multiple records usually you can either add the records explicitly (eg `[ {a:1, b:...}, {a:2, b:...}, {a:3, b:...}, {a:4, b:...} ]`) or using more generic code to achieve the same result. After that use flatten() or flatMap() to flatten each subarray into a single output.

In the script you shared the issue is that it is outputting one array for a field, not an array of of the detail records.

It also adds unneeded complexity. Why to convert strings to numbers if they are going to be output as a string? If you want to be sure they are a number then use a number. The way the mapping is done is too complex and doesn't communicate the intention.

I rewrote the script to have a variable that has the mappings. I can map over the entries to get the "number" of records to generate and apply the variable to get the value for the current key. I used output JSON just to illustrate the method. I recommend to use JSON or DW outputs for debugging, then when you have the structure as desired change to a flatfile output. Note how the expression inside flatMap() returns an array of item, which would be the same if we used an explicit array instead.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json  

var fieldsMapping = {
  "Statement_Message_ID__c": "014205",
  "Option_Set__c": "019303",
  "ASC__c": "011206",
  "CDF23__c": "008902"
}
---
{
  vps: {
    vps: [
      {
        ":USRDSB:-SOURCE": {
          ":USRDSB:-SOURCE": "SOURCE",
          ":USRDSB:-SOURCE-ID ": "MULESOFT"
        },
        ":USRDSB:-HEADER": {
          ":USRDSB:-HEADER": "HEADER",
          ":USRDSB:-TRANSMISSION-ID": "VTY"
        },
        ":USRDSB:-DETAIL-RECORD": payload flatMap (item) -> 
            entriesOf(fieldsMapping) map {
                ":USRDSB:-FIELD-IND": $.value,
                ":USRDSB:-CARD-NBR": item.TSYS_ID__c,
                ":USRDSB:-CUST-IND": "D",
                ":USRDSB:-FIELD-DATA": item.Statement_Message_ID__c
            }
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "vps": {
    "vps": [
      {
        ":USRDSB:-SOURCE": {
          ":USRDSB:-SOURCE": "SOURCE",
          ":USRDSB:-SOURCE-ID ": "MULESOFT"
        },
        ":USRDSB:-HEADER": {
          ":USRDSB:-HEADER": "HEADER",
          ":USRDSB:-TRANSMISSION-ID": "VTY"
        },
        ":USRDSB:-DETAIL-RECORD": [
          {
            ":USRDSB:-FIELD-IND": "014205",
            ":USRDSB:-CARD-NBR": "12346849",
            ":USRDSB:-CUST-IND": "D",
            ":USRDSB:-FIELD-DATA": "15673"
          },
          {
            ":USRDSB:-FIELD-IND": "019303",
            ":USRDSB:-CARD-NBR": "12346849",
            ":USRDSB:-CUST-IND": "D",
            ":USRDSB:-FIELD-DATA": "15673"
          },
          {
            ":USRDSB:-FIELD-IND": "011206",
            ":USRDSB:-CARD-NBR": "12346849",
            ":USRDSB:-CUST-IND": "D",
            ":USRDSB:-FIELD-DATA": "15673"
          },
          {
            ":USRDSB:-FIELD-IND": "008902",
            ":USRDSB:-CARD-NBR": "12346849",
            ":USRDSB:-CUST-IND": "D",
            ":USRDSB:-FIELD-DATA": "15673"
          },
          {
            ":USRDSB:-FIELD-IND": "014205",
            ":USRDSB:-CARD-NBR": "12347015",
            ":USRDSB:-CUST-IND": "D",
            ":USRDSB:-FIELD-DATA": "15839"
          },
          {
            ":USRDSB:-FIELD-IND": "019303",
            ":USRDSB:-CARD-NBR": "12347015",
            ":USRDSB:-CUST-IND": "D",
            ":USRDSB:-FIELD-DATA": "15839"
          },
          {
            ":USRDSB:-FIELD-IND": "011206",
            ":USRDSB:-CARD-NBR": "12347015",
            ":USRDSB:-CUST-IND": "D",
            ":USRDSB:-FIELD-DATA": "15839"
          },
          {
            ":USRDSB:-FIELD-IND": "008902",
            ":USRDSB:-CARD-NBR": "12347015",
            ":USRDSB:-CUST-IND": "D",
            ":USRDSB:-FIELD-DATA": "15839"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This answer is just to explain a method to generate multiple records. You can change the script to add details that you didn't explain in your question.